# Is it possible to create a selection sort algorithm within an already existing selection sort in Java?

Tags: java, algorithm, sorting, double, selection-sort

Is it possible to create a selection sort within an already existing selection sort? Let's say for instance I want to sort dogs by their tail length, and if two dogs have the same length of tail, I want to sort them by their name. How would one go about this? Here is the code, I'd like them to be within the same block of code.

```
  public List<Dog> sortDogsGetTailLength() {
    for (int a = 0; a < listOfDogs.size() - 1; a++) {
        double minValue = listOfDogs.get(a).getTailLength();
        int minIndex = a;

        for (int b = a + 1; b < listOfDogs.size(); b++) {
            if (minValue > listOfDogs.get(b).getTailLength()) {
                minValue = listOfDogs.get(b).getTailLength();
                minIndex = b;
            }
        }
        if (minIndex != a) {
            Dog temp = listOfDogs.get(a);
            listOfDogs.set(a, listOfDogs.get(minIndex));
            listOfDogs.set(minIndex, temp);
        }
    }
    return listOfDogs;
}

//Sorted by name
public List<Dog> sortDogsGetName() {
    for (int a = 0; a < listOfDogs.size() - 1; a++) {
        String minValue = listOfDogs.get(a).getName();
        int minIndex = a;

        for (int b = a + 1; b < listOfDogs.size(); b++) {
            if (listOfDogs.get(b).getName().compareTo(minValue) < 0) {
                minValue = listOfDogs.get(b).getName();
                minIndex = b;
            }
        }
        if (minIndex != a) {
            Dog tempa = listOfDogs.get(a);
            listOfDogs.set(a, listOfDogs.get(minIndex));
            listOfDogs.set(minIndex, tempa);
        }
    }
    return listOfDogs;
}
```

Comment: Just make the comparison between two dogs more or less exactly the way you described it: first compare tail lengths; if one is longer than the other, stop right there because you have your answer; otherwise, it the tails are the same length, then compare names.

Comment: As you have things now, you'd need to write a third `sortDogs...` method which is practically a duplicate of either `sortDogsGetName()` or `sortDogsGetTailLength()`, but differing only in the part that does the actual comparing of dogs.  It's the quickest way to add a new sorting option, but it will quickly become unmanageable if you starting finding lots of other ways you'd like to sort your dogs...

Comment: If you'd like a better way to go, look into using a single sort method that accepts a `Comparator` as an argument. [`Collections.sort()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#sort-java.util.List-java.util.Comparator-) is a good example.  With this scheme, you only need to write new `Comparator`s to introduce new sort orders.

Answer (score 0):

1. Maybe you can use `sortDogsGetTailLength()` first.
2. Then devide the sorted list to sublists that contains dogs with the same tail length. This should take O(n).
3. Then sort the sublists using `sortDogsGetName()`. This is O(n) as well.
4. After all, you can merge all the sublists to a single sorted list.

Please correct me if there is anything wrong. Thanks!

Comment: Isn't Selection sort (N^2)?  On the other hand what your suggesting is more like radex sort, which has a O(N), with a rather hefty K value.